# Mail broken by newlines after sending with PHPMailer

Tags: php, linux, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer in order to send a mail as follows

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->isHTML();

$mail->setFrom('from@server.com', 'server');
$mail->addReplyTo('user@myfavoritemailprovider.com', 'user');
$mail->addAddress('admin@server.com');
$mail->Subject = $subject;

$mail->AltBody = getPlainMail($data);
$mail->Body = getHTMLMail($data);

try {
  $mail->send();
  echo "SUCCESS";
} catch(phpmailerException $e) {
  echo "FAILURE: ", $e->errorMessage();
}
```

This works perfectly fine to send mails using MAMP on my good old Mac OS X, but when I run this code on the Linux server where it should end up, something strange happens to the mails. Spaces appearing randomly in the content and styles not being applied randomly turned out to be a consequence of blank lines between every two lines in the body of the received mail. For a simple example this could look like

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Test</title></head><bo=

dy><main><section style=3D"color:red;"><p style=3D"color=

:black;">test</p></section></main></body></html>
```

whereas it should be something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Test</title></head><bo=
dy><main><section style=3D"color:red;"><p style=3D"color=
:black;">test</p></section></main></body></html>
```

in order to be correct. I tried to figure out where these blank lines come from, but I could not find anything. The strangest thing might even be that when I replace `$mail->send(); echo "SUCCESS";` by

```
$mail->preSend();
echo htmlspecialchars($mail->getSentMIMEMessage());
```

I get the expected result.

Would anyone have an idea where these blank lines are coming from? Any hints are appreciated

Comment: I remember a question like this some time ago and I can't for the life of me remember what the problem was that I do remember posting a comment or an answer for it. I added the "linux" tag to the question since it is relevant to the problem. I'll try and see if I can't find it amidst my many answers.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer 5.2 has a problem with inconsistent line break formats. Have a try with [the 6.0 branch](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/6.0) (not yet released) which avoids the problem, or try setting `$mail->LE = "\r\n";` and ensuring all your content uses the same line break format.

Comment: Setting `$mail->LE = "\r\n"` causes only more blank lines. Especially around the declarations of content-type, etc. (read: the body of the mail becomes the raw MIME body with lots of blank lines). Let's see what the 6.0 branch has to offer...

Comment: Does the 6.0 branch coincidentally avoid the problem by not sending the mail? The `echo "SUCCESS"` was executed, but I don't get any mails when executing from the server. From my local MAMP, it does work as expected...

Comment: What happens if you submit via SMTP to localhost? Try `$mail->isSMTP(); $mail->Host = 'localhost';`. I've seen various instances of `mail()` corrupting content when SMTP does not.

Comment: After some navigating around on my site, I managed to send a mail with the 6.0 branch, but it has the same problem as setting `$mail->LE = "\r\n"`.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the submission phase? PHPMailer only calls mail(), so if what you're feeding in looks right, it must be happening after that.

Comment: I was also thinking that, but when using sendmail, I get the same behaviour.  Would you know if these use the same approach to send mails? I am planning to try out SMTP, but up to now I got some kind of minimal installation (only `class.phpmailer.php`). I have to go in a minute, so I will probably only be able to let you know how that went tomorrow.

Comment: PHP simply calls your local sendmail binary anyway, so there's not much difference. Direct SMTP is usually faster because sendmail binaries just open a synchronous SMTP connection to localhost anyway.

Comment: It turns out that both `mail` as `sendmail` on the server screwed up my nice mail. Sending through SMTP worked, but I had to use the SMTP server that comes with the website. The localhost refused the connection (which makes me wonder why the binaries were able to send mails). Thanks for the guidance!